# ListView onTouchListener is omitting fling

Tags: android, listview

I've wrote this onTouchListener to hide/show actionBar on listview scroll, similar to current functionality in Instagram app. Everything works fine except listView will not fling. I know I've blocked that action somehow, but I'm still a novice and cant figure it out. Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

```
list.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int newTextPosition = (int) (text.getY() * -1);
        int move;               

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                startY = event.getY();
                maxPath = text.getHeight();

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                v.performClick();

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                newY = event.getY();                        
                move = (int) (newY - startY);

                // Going UP
                if(newY < startY){

                    if((text.getY() * -1) == text.getHeight()){
                        startY = event.getY();
                        return false;
                    }

                    int maxPath = (int) (text.getHeight() + text.getY());                               

                    if((move * -1) > maxPath){
                        move = maxPath * -1;
                    }

                    text.setY(text.getY() + move);
                    list.setY(list.getY() + move);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) list.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = list.getHeight() + (move * -1);
                    list.setLayoutParams(params);

                    break;

                }

                // Going DOWN
                if(newY > startY){

                    if((text.getY() * -1) == 0){
                        startY = event.getY();
                        return false;
                    }

                    if(text.getY() >= 0){
                        move = 0;
                    }

                    if(move > newTextPosition)
                        move = newTextPosition;

                    text.setY(text.getY() + move);
                    list.setY(list.getY() + move);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) list.getLayoutParams();
                    params.height = list.getHeight() + (move * -1);
                    list.setLayoutParams(params);

                    break;


                }                                       

        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

EDIT: From some reason returning false at the end did the job. Any explanation is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Captain here with an explanation!

When you return true from overriding [onTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) on Views or from the OnTouchListeners [onTouch()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29) method, you tell android that this touch event has been 'consumed'. This way the touch event won't be passed back to the underlying views and will stop there. This is good when you need to override what happens on a touch event, but if you need the default action to happen you must return false, this way you tell android that the event wasn't 'consumed' and it must notify every other listener that a touch event has happened.

So by returning true, you had overridden the default behavior, which was the swipe and so it wasn't called on any touch event, because you 'consumed' all touch events.

Comment: So if I understood  corectly, if I return true event will be consumed by view with that listener and if I return false it will be consumed by view with the listener and any underlying view? Whay did return true omited fling of the listview then?

Comment: If a method that deals with touch, so one of the two above, returns true it will consume the event. By consuming it means that the event won't be reported to any of the other [observers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). In your case you have two observers (listeners). Yours and listviews swipe. But your listener had a higher priority in getting the event, so when you got the event and returned true, you told the android not to pass the event to any other listeners. So the code which does the swiping never got executed.